# Insert Sql Server

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela com várias colunas. O identificador único é o ID, mas a minha questão é o seguinte:

Tenho uma **coluna versão**, nela quero que seja inserido apenas um valor sem repetição. Como posso implementar isso?

Comment: E se criasse um valor default para a coluna, assim na hora do `insert` passaria como `NULL`, e automaticamente seria preenchido pelo default, o que acha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve fazer com que sua coluna tenha uma `constraint` do tipo `unique`.

Em um editor como o *SQL Server Management Studio*, você deve se dirigir aos índices da tabela e criar um índice único para a coluna.

Já via código, você faz algo assim:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX NomeDoIndice ON dbo.[Tabela com várias colunas]([Versão]);
```

Note que o código acima supõe que a tabela de chama realmente `Tabela com várias colunas` e que o nome da coluna realmente é `Versão`. Você pode usar os nomes reais das suas tabela e coluna, e o nome do índice pode ser qualquer nome arbitrário.

Se você criar um índice único, toda vez que tentar inserir um registro na tabela com um valor na coluna versão que já exista, o SQL disparará um erro. A mensagem do erro explicará que a tabela não permite repetição nessa coluna.

Comment: Funcionou. Muito Obrigada :)